# How come rugby isn't very popular in India?

Tags: history, rugby

In most countries that once were part of the British Empire, rugby and cricket are very popular.  I am trying to explain why rugby, however, never caught on in India and perhaps the West Indies.  Cricket, on the other hand, is very popular there.

E.g. are there cultural reasons against rough sports in those parts of the world?